# Template type deduction for rvalue arguments

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, overloading, rvalue

I understand the forwarding method in C++11.

```
template <class T> void foo(T &&)
```

foo will now accept both lvalues and rvalues.

My problem is when I overload foo furthermore.
Consider this simple code:

```
template <class T> class A {};

template <class T> void foo(T &&obj) {}
template <class T> void foo(A<T> &&obj) {}

int main() {
  int i;
  A<int> a;
  foo(i); // calls foo(T &&) as I want
  foo(a); // calls foo(T &&), but I want it to call foo(A<T> &&)
  return 0;
}
```

If I call `foo` with an `A < int > &` (lvalue) object, it will call `foo(T &&)`, and not `foo(A < T > &&)`. In the definition of `foo(T &&obj)`, I managed to differentiate with std and custom traits if `obj` is `A<T>` or not, but this produces very very messy code, as I must call the `A` method from `obj`, and `obj` is declared as `T`, and not as `A < T >`.
Reordering declarations or adding lvalue overloads don't solve the problem.

Hope I made myself understood.
I provided a simplified code in order to zone in the problem.
I am implementing a custom `Optional < T >` class (similar to `boost::optional`) and I have this problem at constructors as I need to be able to create (and assign) an `Optional < T >` object from another `Optional < T >`, `Optional < U >`, `T` or `U` object. (where `T` is the type held by the optional object to be created, `U` is a different type, convertible to `T`).

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Stack Overflow Rule of Thumb #2: If the OP begins with "I understand", they don't. There's something special about the deduction of `T` that doesn't work the same way for `A<T>`.

Comment: It might be easiest to add the desired overloads directly, like [in this example](http://ideone.com/jN2T2m). More convoluted solutions using SFINAE can probably be created, but I don't think there's much gain in those.

Comment: T is a universal reference whereas A<T> is just a plain old rvalue reference

Comment: @KerrekSB Have to ask, what is Rule of Thumb #1?

Comment: @MattPhillips [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: Careful: `foo(2)` and `foo(i)` don't in fact call the same function.  The first is `foo<int>(int&&)`.  The second is `foo<int&>(int&)`.

Comment: @MattPhillips: I'm not really sure, mainly because I make these up on the fly (you'll find more in old comments of mine). There's definitely one about "my code compiles perfectly fine", and another about "we all know that..."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

During template argument deduction for a function call, the special rules for "universal references" only apply if the parameter type is a cv-unqualified template parameter [temp.deduct.call]/3

[`P` is the parameter type of the function template, and `A` is the type of the argument]

> If `P` is an rvalue reference to a cv-unqualified template parameter and the argument is an lvalue, the type “lvalue reference to `A`” is used in place of `A` for type deduction. [*Example:*
>
> ```
> template <class T> int f(T&&);
> template <class T> int g(const T&&);
> int i;
> int n1 = f(i); // calls f<int&>(int&)
> int n2 = f(0); // calls f<int>(int&&)
> int n3 = g(i); // error: would call g<int>(const int&&), which
> // would bind an rvalue reference to an lvalue
> ```
>
> — *end example* ]

Similarly, these rules *do not* apply to the parameter type `A<T>&&`. It is not a "universal reference" but purely an rvalue-reference type.

---

If you want to have a ranking between two constructors, where the `A<T>`-version shall be more specialized (a better match), you can:

- provide <strike>two</strike>three overloads `A<T> const&`, `A<T>&` (thanks, [Eric Niebler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/195873/eric-niebler)) and `A<T>&&` in addition to the `T&&` generic version
- use SFINAE; provide two overloads with a parameter `T&&` and check if `T` is a specialization of `A<T>`

Comment: You would need a third overload for `A<T> &` in addition to `A<T> const &` and `A<T> &&`. It's messy.

Comment: @EricNiebler Oh! You're right, *more specialized* is only used as a tie-breaker after considering the required conversions (in this case, a Qualification Conversion for `A<T> const&` and an lvalue argument of type `A<T>` vs. Exact Match for the `T&&` function).